# not caching checkbox selection

Tags: jquery, caching, dom

Is there some way to prevent the browser's caching of checkbox selections post refresh?

**Use-case:**

- User selects some checkboxes on a page. At the same time some internal server state changes.
- User refreshes the page. The server renders the page with different checkboxes selected than before, but the users browser in most cases shows the old set of selections

In these cases i usually need to run some js to set the right selection, but is there a better way?

Comment: perhaps this article could help? http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1584-Preventing-Form-Caching-With-Javascript-And-jQuery.htm

Comment: from article: "Include the jQuery Javascript library. I am not sure
why this makes a difference, but by including it, the
Javascript below takes effect." ... this makes me want to find a better solution than the one provided by a voodoo programmer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `autocomplete='off'` to the checkbox's parent form tag